# Vectorized multi index operation without any looping or hard coding

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, vectorization, multi-index

I'm not sure if my request is possible, but here's what I'd like to do:

- Create a dataframe with N multi indexes and 2 columns (X and Y) for each multi index. then I want to create a Z column for each multi index with is a sum of X and Y columns of the respective multi index.
- All operations must be vectorized and I dont want any loops or hard coding (wouldn't scale with N > 1000, per say). The new number of columns should be N of multi index * 3 (x,y,z).

Can this be done?

Here are two code examples using hard coding and list comprehension / looping, which is not what I want.

List Comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define N as the number of multi indexes
N = 3

# Create a list of tuples for the multi index levels
levels = [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('x', 'y')]

# Use itertools.product to generate all combinations of levels
from itertools import product
columns = list(product(*levels))

# Create a dataframe with random integers from 0 to 9 and 10 rows
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, len(columns))), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns))

# Sum x and y columns for each multi index level using groupby and assign to z column using loop comprehension
df[[(*level, 'z') for level in levels[0]]] = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Hardcoding:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define N as the number of multi indexes
N = 3

# Create a list of tuples for the multi index levels
levels = [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('x', 'y')]

# Use itertools.product to generate all combinations of levels
from itertools import product
columns = list(product(*levels))

# Create a dataframe with random integers from 0 to 9 and 10 rows
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, len(columns))), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns))

# Sum x and y columns for each multi index level using groupby and assign to z column
df[('A', 'z')] = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()[('A')]
df[('B', 'z')] = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()[('B')]
df[('C', 'z')] = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()[('C')]

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A     B     C      A   B   C
   x  y  x  y  x  y   z   z   z
0  8  5  9  5  9  9  13  14  18
1  7  4  6  6  0  2  11  12   2
2  4  1  5  1  5  8   5   6  13
3  5  3  5  6  2  0   8  11   2
4  4  3  5  9  3  0   7  14   3
5  9  4  8  3  3  4  13  11   7
6  0  5  7  3  6  1   5  10   7
7  2  9  2  8  0  9  11  10   9
8  5  2  7  5  1  9   7  12  10
9  7  3  9  2  5  5  10  11  10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `pd.concat`:

```py
df2 = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, ['z']])

df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A     B     C      A   B   C
   x  y  x  y  x  y   z   z   z
0  1  9  6  8  5  3  10  14   8
1  1  3  5  7  7  9   4  12  16
2  2  9  8  1  8  7  11   9  15
3  0  0  0  3  6  5   0   3  11
4  9  7  7  4  7  7  16  11  14
5  6  7  8  1  2  0  13   9   2
6  1  3  5  3  4  4   4   8   8
7  7  9  0  3  3  0  16   3   3
8  6  0  4  7  7  9   6  11  16
9  4  4  0  8  4  8   8   8  12
```

Comment: Yes. That works. however, the performance is actually slightly worse than the list comprehension version (LC 643 µs / Your implementation 735 µs). Is there a way to apply a parallelized/vectorized approach to calculate this on all multi indexes in a very efficient manner?